# How to build a project in android studio from google git, it has no gradle file?

Tags: android, gradle

I have downloaded the source code of DeskClock from google git from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/pie-release-2. But when I import it in android studio, it shows error due to missing gradle file. How can I import it in Android Studio and build the project? Am I doing something completely wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

After you download the project, you can open terminal and execute following commands

- `gradle wrapper`

> Generates Gradle wrapper files.

and

- `gradle init`

> Depends on: wrapper
>
> Generates a Gradle project.

After that, you can add all dependency to `build.gradle`